# How to resolve error "invalid types 'int [x][const char*]' for array subscript"?

Tags: c++

I keep getting the error in subject, below is the code. Especially in type of constant N; I would like to count 10 100 and 100 to infinity.

What is wrong and how best to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 100
#define start 1

int main()
{
    system("cls");
    long int a1,a2;
    long int res1,res2;
    long int c1,c2;
    a1=start;
    a2=a1+N;
    res1=(a2+2)/5;
    res2=(a2+4)/6;

    long int i,q,z,g;
    int nums[N];

    for (i=start; i<(start + N); i++) {
        nums["i<start"+1]=10*i+8;
    }
    for (i=1; i<N; i++) {
        for (q=1;q<=res1;q++) {
            c2=(a2+q+2)/(10*q-8);
            c1=(a1+q+2)/(10*q-8)+1;

            for (g=c1;g<c2;g++) {
                z=(10*q+8)*g-(q-2);
                if ((z-start+1)<N)
                    nums[z-start+1]=0;
                else 
                    break;
            }
        }
        for (q=1;q<=res2;q++) {
            c2=(a2+q)/(10*q-6);
            c1=(a1+q)/(10*q-6)+1;
            for (g=c1;g<=c2;g++) {
                z=(10*q-6)*g+q;
                if ((z-start+1)<N)
                    nums["z-start"+1]=0;
                else 
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
    for (i=1;i<N;i++)
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: `nums["i<start"+1]` makes no sense whatsoever. Whatever that's supposed to be, it's wrong.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It could be an ingenious stack overflow exploit.

Comment: @nicomp :) but no.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the compiler already says what's the problem.
`nums["i<start"+1]` and `nums["z-start"+1]` leads to that error. You cannot index an element through a `string` (also called `const char*`). Simply replace it with `nums[i-start+1]` (or whatever you meant with `<`) and `nums[z-start+1]`.

Also your code is not really well written. Don't use short variable names like `N` or `g` or `c2`, it's just confusing (prefer long / logical ones). Commenting your project and learning about compiler errors also never hurts.